# Printing out the sum of set of numbers in Java

Tags: java, loops, while-loop

I'm currently practising with while loops and I'm trying to get my loop to add a set of numbers in range between 1 and 10, I've got the code printing out the numbers but not the sum: can someone help me with this?

```
 public void AddInArray()
 {
    int index = 0;
    while(index <= 10){
        System.out.println(index);
        index++;
    }

 }
```

Comment: What array? There is no array here.

Comment: Well, you're not even trying to get a sum there ...

Comment: Ahh I just called it array,  there is no array

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 public void addInArray(int[] arr)
 {
    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while(index < arr.length){
        System.out.println(index);
        sum += arr[i];
        index++;
    }
    System.out.println(sum);

 }
```

Now to call it,

```
int[] arr = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
addInArray(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

So having used the code from the 11thdimension, i adapted it so now it works in my code:

```
public void AddInArray(int length)
{
    int index = 0;
    int sum = 0;
    while(index <= length){
        System.out.println(index);
        sum += index;
        index++;



    }
    System.out.println(sum);
}
```

So what this does is:

while the index is less than the length, print out the index, it also add the index to the integer known as sum and finally it increments the index by one. one the loop is finished it then carry's out the other function which is to print out the sum that has been storing the int values. it prints out the numbers from 1-10 and the sum of them 55.

Thanks for the help guys.

Comment: Just a couple of comments. Use addInArray as your method name rather than starting with a capital "A" (convention), and not using the term "Array" here even since it can create a bit of a confusion given the idea associated with "Array" [as seen in 11thdimension's solution being different].